# Jquery thorws error on post back when finding .dynamic function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-tooltip

i am using jquery to show a tooltip popup the code i am using is below

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MainEndRequestHandler);

            $(MainEndRequestHandler);

            function MainEndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                loadeverthingmaster();
            }

            function loadeverthingmaster(){
                 try
                 {  

                          $(".download_now").tooltip({ 
                              effect: 'slide',
                              delay:300                                                               

                          }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });          


                       $(".help-bubble-link[title]").tooltip({

                          // tweak the position
                          offset: [10, 2],

                          // use the "slide" effect
                          effect: 'slide',

                          // add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
                       }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });

                 }
                 catch(err)
                 {
                     alert(err);
                 } 
            }

        </script>
```

but when i load my page i get this error

TypeError: $(".download_now").tooltip({effect: "slide", delay: 300}).dynamic is not a function

I have no clue why this is happening. anyone got any idea or solutino...

Regards

Comment: This is a poorly formatted question.. You did not tell us what plugin you are using so it's hard to give you a direct answer. Have you tried to comment out your code for "$(".download_now")... " and see if your "$(".help-bubble-link[title]")... " runs as expected? I think you need to be supplying a string or a "title" for the first tooltip effect to work because I don't think that plugin is designed to works with DOM elements.

Comment: He is using this library w/ jquery http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the order you import your script in.  Make sure this script tag is below the jquery-tooltip plugins import.  Also make sure jquery and jquery-ui are imported above the jquery-tooltip plugins.  Also you may want to try wrapping this code with document.ready() to make sure all script is loaded like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MainEndRequestHandler);

            $(MainEndRequestHandler);

            function MainEndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                loadeverthingmaster();
            }

            function loadeverthingmaster(){
                 try
                 {  

                          $(".download_now").tooltip({ 
                              effect: 'slide',
                              delay:300                                                               

                          }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });          


                       $(".help-bubble-link[title]").tooltip({

                          // tweak the position
                          offset: [10, 2],

                          // use the "slide" effect
                          effect: 'slide',

                          // add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
                       }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });

                 }
                 catch(err)
                 {
                     alert(err);
                 } 
            }
});
        </script>
```

To make sure you have the proper libraries you could also try swapping the jquery import and the jquery tools import with this import that contains jquery + jquery tools + dynamic plugin:

```
<!-- jQuery Library + ALL jQuery Tools -->
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Also try:

```
 $(".help-bubble-link['title']").tooltip({  //notice change in this line

                          // tweak the position
                          offset: [10, 2],

                          // use the "slide" effect
                          effect: 'slide',

                          // add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
                       }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });
```

Comment: Every thing works find for the first time when the page loads but then after any postback it does't work...